# How does 'UQ' function if another field is 'PK' in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm creating a schema for a database using MySQL's workbench. One of my tables contains fields for a personId, as well as a national id number if they have one (which they may not).

The personId field is the one used as a unique identifier throughout the schema, so I've ticked the "PK" and "NN" options for it. Now I'd like to be able to ensure that the system won't allow a new insert with a different personId if it has the same national id as an entity that already exists. However, national ids are not primary keys and may in fact be null.

I've been looking at the 'UQ' option, but I can't find clear documentation on what it actually does. I'm worried it'll create the numbers automatically when I actually want them to be inserted by a user or left null. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UQ tags a field as a [unique key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key). This enforces uniqueness in a given field, except for NULLs. This is exactly what I need for my national id field.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html :

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.